# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3-x\cos x }{\sin x}$ without l'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

What techniques I could use to solve this limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3-x\cos x }{\sin x}$$

without l'Hopital?

When I use l'Hopital the limit is $-1$.

With l'Hopital
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x^2-1\cdot \cos x+x\sin x}{\cos x}=$$
$$=\frac{3\cdot 0-1\cdot 1+1\cdot 0}{1}=$$
$$=\frac{-1}{1}=-1$$

Comment: You should show your work with l'Hospital.

Comment: Note that $\frac{x^3-x\cos x}{\sin x}=\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)(x^2-\cos x)$.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3-x%5Ccos%20x%7D%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%24&p=1), there's the somewhat similar [Solving $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x+ x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} $ without L'Hopitals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3961195), where this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3961196) uses the same basic approach as in my comment above, and in [user's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724815) below.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, we can/should proceed as follows

$$\frac{x^3-x\cos x }{\sin x}=\frac{x}{\sin x}(x^2-\cos x)$$

and then use standard limit $\frac{x}{\sin x} \to ?$ and continuity for the other factor.

More in general, I suggest to avoid l'Hopital to solve limits as a first step and always try with, in the order

- continuity/sustituition (not intederminate expression)
- manipulation to get standard limits
- Taylor expansion
- l'Hopital only for some particualr limits (e.g. integral functions)

Refer also to

- [What are the most important well-known limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3595668)
- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333)

Answer (score 0):

You can recover a derivative after substituting $x=\arcsin y$ :

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3-x\cos x}{\sin x} = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{\arcsin^3y-\sqrt{1-y^2} \arcsin y}{y} \\ = \frac{d}{dy} \left[\arcsin^3y-\sqrt{1-y^2} \arcsin y\right]\bigg|_{y=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Taylor series approximation to say as $x \to 0$ we have $\sin x \approx x$ and $\cos x \approx 1$. Then, pluge in these two in the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x^3-x\cos x }{\sin x}\approx \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3-x }{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^2-1 = -1$$